# WPF TextBox/RichTextBox - Show line numbers

Tags: c#, wpf

What is the simplest way to show line numbers for native WPF controls when wrap mode is on? (Without using 3rd party controls.)

Comment: Remember that container height / line height = line count, this should get you started. There is no "inbuilt" way if you mean that, and this is pretty easy already.